# openCV 3.0: how to save/load cv::ml::boost model

Tags: c++, opencv, adaboost

Back in openCV2.x, cvBoost model can be saved/loaded as described in this
[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869954/opencv-c-problems-working-with-cvboost-adaboost-classifer)

In openCV3.0, I manage to train an adaboost model (cv::ml::boost Model1) and save it into a yml file with

```
    Model1.save("model.yml");
```

But it seems that the following load function is not implemented:

```
    Model1.load("model.yml");
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [3.0 doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#statmodel-load) we can see that `StatModel::load` is a static template method:

> C++: `Ptr<_Tp> StatModel::load(const String& filename)`

Also see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#boost-create):

> `StatModel::load<Boost>(filename)` to load the pre-trained model

So you can load the model like

```
Ptr<Boost> mdl = StatModel::load<Boost>("model.yml");
```